# Byteslicing requires an int?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, udp

So I'm making a UDP host discoverer, but this line of code is giving me a headache. This is the first time I've used bitslicing.

```
    ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:20])
```

gives me the error
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

The buffer is just a packet received from a socket.

```
import socket

import os
import struct
from ctypes import *

# host ot listen on
host = "192.168.0.102"

# our IP header
class IP(Structure):
    _fields_= [
        ("ihl",             c_ubyte, 4),
        ("version",         c_ubyte, 4),
        ("tos",             c_ubyte),
        ("len",             c_ushort),
        ("id",              c_ushort),
        ("offset",          c_ushort),
        ("ttl",             c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num",    c_ubyte),
        ("sum",             c_ushort),
        ("src",             c_ulong),
        ("dst",             c_ulong)
    ]

def _new_(self, socket_buffer=None):
    return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)

def _init_(self, socket_buffer=None):

    # map protocol constants to their names
    self.protocol_map = {1: "ICMP", 6:"TCP", 17:"UDP"}

    # human readable IP addresses
    self.src_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L",self.src))
    self.dst_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L",self.dst))

    # human readable protocol
    try:
        self.protocol = self.protocol_map[self.protocol_num]
    except:
        self.protocol = str(self.protocol_num)

#this should look familiar to sniffy.py
if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)

sniffer.bind((host, 0))
sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

try:

    while True:

        #Read in a packet
        raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]

        #Create an IP header from the first 20 bytes of the buffer
        ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:20])

        #Print out the protocol that was detected and the hosts
        print ("Protocol: %s %s -> %s" % (ip_header.protocol,        ip_header.src_address, ip_header.dst_address))

    #handle CTRL-C
    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        #If we're using Windows, turn off promiscuous mode
        if os.name == "nt":
            sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

Comment: You are using python 2.7 or 3.X?

Comment: Look into [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module (unpack).

Comment: 3.X, although the book I am learning from is 2.7, I'm editing it as I go to try to make it compatible.

Comment: Code to *reproduces* is needed. What book, what is `IP`?

Comment: What is `IP`, and why are you passing it `raw_buffer[0:20]`? Why did you expect that to work?

Comment: Black Hat Python, IP is an analogue of the C structure to map an ip address. Editing in all code now.

Comment: `__init__` and `__new__` take two underscores on each side, among other problems.

Comment: Ah. I'm used to just using init() in Java. I don't know the python syntax.

Comment: Putting two underscores by the __init__ and __new__ fixed it. Thank you all.